# Extracting contract's variables state

Tags: solidity, web3js

Hello Ethereum community, I'm building a mobile app with ionic, i want that app to acces a specific smart contract address (that i made and own) and extract variables of that contract, at first i thought about using web3.js but it requires a RPC layer to work with and implies downloading the whole blockchain wich is not practical as a quick mobile app, second guess was using etherscan api but i dont find it usefull on that matter or i'm missing something. I need some suggestions thank you.

TL;DR Extract smart contract variables on a mobile app without downloading the whole blockchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Infura](https://infura.io). They're a public node that you can query directly. Something like this:

```
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/YOUR-API-KEY"));
web3.eth.contract(...).at("0x...").myPublicVariable(function (err, value) { ... });
```